# PdfLayer.GetTitle() always returning null

Tags: c#, itext7

C# itext 7.1.4 (NuGet release) doesn't seem to parse OCG/layer titles correctly.

The C# code below should read a pdf, print all layer titles, turn off the layer visibility and save it to the dest file.

Example pdf file: https://docdro.id/qI479di

```cs
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using System;

namespace PDFSetOCGVisibility
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var src = @"layer-example.pdf";
            var dest = @"layer-example-out.pdf"; ;
            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src), new PdfWriter(dest));
            var Catalog = pdf.GetCatalog();
            var ocProps = Catalog.GetOCProperties(false);
            var layers = ocProps.GetLayers();
            foreach(var layer in layers)
            {
                var title = layer.GetTitle();
                Console.WriteLine($"title: {title ?? "null"}");
                layer.SetOn(false);
            }
            pdf.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Expected output is:

```cs
title: Layer 1
title: Layer 2
```

Actual output is:

```cs
title: null
title: null
```

Writing the file with disabled layers works fine but the layer titles are always null.

Comment: What is the output value of your `layers` **before** assigning `title` ? Have you made sure that they are not `null` before assignment?

Comment: layers is correctly set to a list with 2 entries, see https://imgur.com/a/3zRSirx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what's the purpose of title/GetTitle() but to get the Name (as displayed on the panel) the following code works:

```
var title = layer.GetPdfObject().GetAsString(PdfName.Name).ToUnicodeString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tested the itext5 version:

```
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace PDFSetOCGVisibility5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var src = @"layer-example.pdf";
            var dest = @"layer-example-out.pdf";
            var reader = new PdfReader(src);
            PdfStamper pdf = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create));
            var layers = pdf.GetPdfLayers();
            foreach (var layer in layers)
            {
                var title = layer.Key;
                Console.WriteLine($"title: {title ?? "null"}");
                layer.Value.On = false;
            }
            pdf.Close();
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

It's working as expected, so this seems to be a regression in itext7